# namespace and template class vector declaration of methods('Vector' does not name a type; did you mean 'perror'?)

Tags: c++, class, templates, namespaces

I have some issues with this program, I can't redefine constructor methods into file CPP. 
The compiler gives me this error:

error: 'Vector' does not name a type; did you mean 'perror' (I'm using c++11);

```
#ifndef ESERCIZIO_1_VECTOR_H
#define ESERCIZIO_1_VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include "container.h"  

namespace lasd
    {
        template <typename T>
        class Vector
        { 

        private:
            T *arr = nullptr;
            int size;
            int length; // number of elements into the array
        public:
            // Default constructor
            Vector();
            // Specific constructor
            Vector(int size, int length = 0);
           }
    #include ''vector.cpp''
    }
#endif
```

This is the file vector.cpp

```
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
    :Vector<T>::Vector(10) {};

template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size, int length )
        :size{size}, length{length}
{
    arr = new T[size];
};
```

Comment: Not sure if you can call cosntructors from one another like that. Why don't you just do `Vector<T>::Vector() : size(10), length(0) { arr = new T[size];}` ?

Comment: You also need to write `template <typename T>` before the definition of the first constructor (in the cpp file). And the semicolon is missing at the end of the class declaration. But you don't need semicolons at the end of the constructor definitions.

Comment: @melk Yes you can, it's called "delegating constructor", a feature that was introduced with C++ 11.

Answer (score 0):

I think the constructor definition should work as is the header file (@Rene) I believe this link is relevant to this problem https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates